# How do I correctly add Source Control after I've started a project in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git

**Problem**: I created a project and didn't start out with source control.  When I try to add Source Control, I can't even see the correct files to commit.

**Solution Attempt 1**: Source Control > Create Git Repositories.

Result: Creates a Master. When I go to commit it asks me if I want to commit GreenThumbIOS and Pods.  I don't need to commit the pods so I only choose my project. My viewcontroller, storyboards, etc. are not visible and I can't push them.

**Solution Attempt 2**: Terminal > $ cd /project > git init > git add . > git commit -m 'initial commit' |

Result: 'On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean'

Image of folder, issue, and project menu:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The second approach (which is the way I would have done it) worked:

> Solution Attempt 2: Terminal >
>
> ```
> $ cd /project > git init > git add . > git commit -m 'initial commit' |
> ```
>
> Result: 'On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean'

That is exactly what you would expect after init, add, commit. You now have created an initial snapshot and you can proceed to develop, push, whatever. You are under source control, which is what you wanted.

If you are in any doubt, do a `git log` and you will see the initial commit and what's in it.